# how to sort Below NSDictionary basis on NSString Date keys?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

How do I sort the below `NSSDictionary` on the basis of keys which are dates in `NSString` Format?

```
Printing description of dictMessageWithDate:
{
    "06:10:2015" =     (
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78e108c0>"
    );
    "25:09:2015" =     (
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78fe8740>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ff5e50>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ff58b0>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x790205c0>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x7901ee00>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x79025990>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x7901f190>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78faab50>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ff8ff0>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ff9860>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ffa1c0>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ffa490>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ff6810>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78f98720>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78f99790>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78f42eb0>"
    );
    "28:09:2015" =     (
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ffad90>"
    );
    "29:09:2015" =     (
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ff1de0>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78edad20>",
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78e7a9d0>"
    );
    "30:09:2015" =     (
        "<ChatMessage: 0x78ec3ac0>"
    );
}
```

Comment: You don't sort a NSDictionary. It's a KEY/VALUE system, not a index (like NSArray) system.

Comment: ... or to put it another way; dictionaries *unordered*. You will have to keep a  separate array of the keys, however consider using a more convenient method of representing the dates as any operation of those dates (i.e. `NSString` to `NSDate` conversion) means a lot of redundent processing.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a reorganisation:

1. Put a *date sent* property on `ChatMessage` (`@property NSDate *dateSent`).  It should already have one, as that's an important property of the message.
2. Keep the chat messages in an `NSArray`, which is an *ordered* collection class.
3. Sort the chat messages like this:

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateSent" 
                                                ascending:YES];
   NSArray *sorted = [unsorted
        sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[dateDescriptor]];
   ```

Comment: but I need to create sections like whatsapp for days

Comment: You can still do that; you need to keep an array of arrays.  The principle is still the same as you would still want the chat messages ordered by date within each section.